# Store and Get Key Value SharedPreferencese android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am developing an application for android and I am new to it, For getting the value from `SharedPreferences`, I copied and pasted this piece of code below :

```
SharedPreferences prefs =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                String myValue = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.my_key),
                        getString(R.string.my_default_key));
```

Obviously this is done inside an Activity, but for storing the `key` `value` into `SharedPreferences` I have some issues it should be done inside a Class which is not an `Activity` therefore the above code is not working.

Question: 
I need to know if there is any way that I can use to store and the `key` `value` pair inside a class, so that I could retrieve the `key` `value` in an`Activity` with the code above or do I have to modify my code and changed it something like the answered question in this link?

[How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Answer (score 2):

Of course! You can use the SharedPreferences inside of your own classes, just pass the context to the class constructor (or however you want to do it) and you should be able to use it normally!

```
public YourClass(Context c) {
    this.ctx = c;
}
```

You pass it then when creating the instance of the class:

```
YourClass cls = new YourClass(getApplicationContext());
```

Then you can use `SharedPreferences` inside of your class!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. In your class, pass in an (application) `Context`, then:

```
SharedPreferences prefs =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write some public static methods in your Application class, and you can set or get some values in your Activity.